# Javascript function triggered at the top of the page instead of the bottom

Tags: javascript

I have this function called getData() that get data from the server with an ajax call;
everything works fine, the only one problem is that the function getData() is called when i scroll back to the top instead of gettin called when i reach the end of the page.

Fun fact, I was working on this a week ago and everything worked fine.

Here's the snippet of Javascript:

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
    getData();
    console.log('bottom');
    }
    });
```

Edit: I found this snippet and this seems to work, very strange.

```
    window.onscroll = function(ev) {
if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) 
{
 getData();
}

};
```

This is my html page:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 results"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var start = 0;
var limit = 15;
var reached_max = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    getData();
});


function getData() {
    if (reached_max)
        return;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {
            getData: 1,
            start: start,
            limit: limit
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == "reached_max")
                reached_max = true;
            else {
                start += limit;
                $(".results").append(response);
            }
        }
    });
}


window.onscroll = function(ev) {
if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    getData();
}
};


/*
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
getData();
console.log('bottom');
}
});
*/
</script>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine for me being triggered only when scrolling to the bottom? I just tried it in a snippet

Comment: Very strange, it work the exact opposite for me

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kjthwu81/2/ this jsfiddle only console logs when at the bottom

Comment: If the jsfiddle works for you, then your issue may potentially have to do with your CSS/html layout

Comment: Or you have something else dynamically affecting the scroll behavior/positions?

Comment: It works fine on jsfiddle but not in my code wtf

Comment: Could you share your html/css/js in a fiddle?

Comment: Try using [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this. Observe the last element in the list and when it comes into view, load more data. Much more performant and easier to maintain.